# Understanding the textbook: Expressing a triple integral in a different order

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I was going over my textbook and have trouble understanding this process:

[image]

Why does the innermost integral have the bounds $\sqrt{y}$ and $1$? The shape on the $xz$ plane looks the same as the one on the $xy$ plane so I figured that you could replace $\sqrt{y}$ with $\sqrt{z}$ in the bounds.

I did a quick calculation on my computer using $f(x,y,z)=xyz$ to check and the results were $0.0125$ and $0.02916667$ respectively. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The two integrals are the same: see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+int_0%5E(x%5E2)+int_0%5Ey+x+y+z+dz+dy+dx) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20int_0%5E(y)%20int_(sqrt(y))%5E1%20x%20y%20z%20dx%20dz%20dy).

As for the limits, the whole "projection" argument sounds too complicated to me. You have 
$$\tag1
0\leq x\leq 1, \ \ 0\leq y\leq x^2,\ \ 0\leq z\leq y. 
$$
If you now want $y$ to be the "independent" variable, you get $0\leq y\leq 1$. You also have, from above, that $0\leq z\leq y$. And, finally, $\sqrt y\leq x\leq 1$ from the first two sets of inequalities in $(1)$.

Comment: The integral I was wondering about is one where everything is the same in the triple integral except for the innermost integral, where instead of $\sqrt{y}$, you have $\sqrt{z}$. Why wouldn't that be allowed since $0\leq z\leq y\leq x^2$?

Comment: Because you cannot choose limits at random. For your choice of limits, the point $(1/2, 1/4, 1/2)$, that belongs the the region $(1)$, does not satisfy your inequalities. So you are considering a different region.

Comment: When they write out the projections of the $xy$-plane and the $xz$-plane, the sets are pretty much the same besides the letter $y/z$. And since thats the innermost integral, i take it that $y$ and $z$ are fixed, so why can't the integral depend on $z$ instead of $y$?

Comment: This is not philosophy. "Pretty much the same" doesn't cut it here: I'm giving you a concrete point that lies inside the original region, but does not satisfy your inequalities, so your inequalities don't describe the original region. By replacing $\sqrt y$ with $\sqrt z$ you are considering a different region.

Comment: I guess that was a poor choice of words and I appreciate you providing a counterexample, but I'm just trying to find the flaw in my intuition. If you had done this question and used the projections approach, how would you have known to use $\sqrt{y}$ after looking at $D_1, D_2, D_3$?

Comment: Yes, now I see what you mean. If you want to use $D_3$, then your "floor" is $0\leq z\leq 1$, $\sqrt z\leq x\leq 1$. But then you need $z\leq y\leq x^2$. Look [here](https://www.math3d.org/plMMEZM5) for a visualization. Click on the green circle to "open" the region and see the interior.

Comment: Forgive me, but if we have that $0\leq x\leq 1$, $0\leq y\leq x^2$, $0\leq z\leq y$, we do have $z\leq y\leq x^2$ since $z\leq y$ and $y\leq x^2$, don't we?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote. Not entirely sure where you are going.

Answer (score 0):

If we use Figure 13, there is a simpler way to compute the limits of integration for any given order.

**Step 1**: For the variable corresponding to the innermost integral ($x$ in this case), visualize a line parallel to the $x$-axis that passes through the solid. Then the surface where such a line would first touch the solid is given by $y= x^2$, and the surface where it would exit the solid is given by $x=1$.

Therefore, the lower and upper limits for $x$ are $\sqrt y$ and $1$ respectively.

**Step 2**: For the remaining two variables ($y$ and $z$ in this case), find the region $R$ in the $yz$-plane that includes all the $y$ and $z$ coordinates being used in the solid. Looking at Figure 13, this 'projection' on $yz$-plane can be intuitively seen as $R= \{(y,z):0\leq y \leq 1,0\leq z \leq y\}$.

**Step 3**: Now the problem has basically been reduced to computing limits for a double integral. Since $y$ is the variable corresponding to the outermost integral, express limits of $z$ in terms of $y$.

Therefore, the lower and upper limits for $z$ are $0$ and $y$ respectively. Whereas the lower and upper limits for $y$ are $0$ and $1$ respectively.

---

> Why does the innermost integral have the bounds $\sqrt y$ and $1$? The shape on
>   the xz plane looks the same as the one on the xy plane so I figured
>   that you could replace $\sqrt y$ with $\sqrt z$ in the bounds.

Based on the above interpretation, replacing $\sqrt y$ with $\sqrt z$ would essentially mean that if an arbitrary line parallel to the $x$-axis were to pass through your solid, it would first touch the solid at $x=\sqrt z$. However, we know that is not the case, and thus doing so would change the solid we are dealing with.